# PHP - "Call to a member function ... on a non-object" when calling parent function

Tags: php, oop, inheritance

All,

I'm a fairly new and I mostly studied OOP with Java.

With this said, here is the relevant code:

**Model.php**

```
class Model{ // Object that represents a connection to the relevant db table
        private $db; //contains the identifiers of the db
        private $dao;

        function createRecord1(){
            return $this->dao->createRecord();
        }
    }
```

**User_Model.php**

```
class Model_user extends Model {
        function __construct($db){
            $this->db=$db;
            $dao=DAO_DBrecord::createUserDAO($this->db);//  This is a static function that calls the DAO constructor with a 'user' table name parameter
            $this->dao=$dao;
        }
    }
```

Then in **Controller_Register.php**, I have this code:

```
//Some other code
$db=DB::createDB();
$userModel=new Model_User($db);
$userID=$userModel->createRecord1();
//Some more code
```

This yields the error message I have in the title.  The line `return $this->dao->createRecord();` inside `Model.php` causes the error.

There is no error if the function `createRecord1()` is placed in `Model_User` instead of in the parent class - but then of course I would have to duplicate it in other children.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: While I'm not certain if it's the cause of your errors, be aware that in PHP, private members are *not* accessible in descendant classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "same" code in Java would result in the same errors.  `$db` and `$dao` are specified as private class members of `Model`, so are not available for you to manipulate directly in classes which extend `Model`.  Try changing

```
class Model {
        private $db;
        private $dao;
        ...
```

to

```
class Model {
        protected $db;
        protected $dao;
        ...
```

You can read more about this in the [PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php):

> Class members declared public can be accessed everywhere. Members declared protected can be accessed only within the class itself and by inherited and parent classes. Members declared as private may only be accessed by the class that defines the member.

Comment: high five. submitted at exactly the same time as me :)

Comment: thanks. Q is a duplicate though, so i deleted mine again.

Comment: Argh...  I should have had the reflex to check for this.  I'm so dumb.  Arghhh  Anyways, many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You don't want `$dao` and `$db` to be `private`. If they are `private`, the subclass does not share access with the parent.

You want them to be `protected`.